# Install phalcon dev tools 3.4

Tags: ubuntu, phalcon, phalcon-devtools

How can I install phalcon dev-tools 3.4 instead of 4?

My phalcon extension is v3.4.5, installed this version because version 4 has some problems with Ubuntu.

So these are the steps I did

1. I git cloned from their official repo https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools.git
2. Checked out to remotes/origin/3.4.x
3. Then I run composer install, but I get the following error:

   > The requested PHP extension ext-phalcon ^4.0.0 has the wrong version (3.4.5) installed. Install or enable PHP's phalcon extension.`

Comment: What command did you use to do git checkout? The composer.json file of `3.4.x` branch requires `ext-phalcon: ~3.3`. Probably you did not checkout properly. https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/blob/3.4.x/composer.json#L26

Answer (score 3):

```sh
composer require phalcon/devtools:3.4.12
```

or

you can clone it from here and then add it your path:

https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools/tree/v3.4.12

also check the [discussion here](https://forum.phalcon.io/discussion/20547/after-generating-a-project-skeleton-i-cant-access-the-project-fr) if you ran into the `handler class cannot be loaded` issue